# "Пока" - это наречие или союз?

Tags: морфология, части-речи, союзы, наречия

> Дорога вела вправо, но я по совету незнакомца продолжал идти по
>   тропинке, **пока** не натолкнулся на изгородь.

***"Пока"*** в данном предложении является союзом или наречием? Как определить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это предложение по своей структуре ближе **к сложному предложению**, а не предложению с однородными сказуемыми, так как сказуемые расположены не компактно, имеют разную грамматическую форму, ПОКА НЕ относится ко второму сказуемому.

**Поэтому ПОКА НЕ ― это союз в сложноподчиненном предложении** с придаточным времени, для проверки можно сделать замену:

Дорога вела вправо, но я по совету незнакомца продолжал идти по тропинке, **(до тех пор) пока (я) не натолкнулся на изгородь.**

Answer (score 1):

В данном предложении это **союз**: он *присоединяет* условие действия "продолжал идти". **Наречием** это слово было бы в случае, если бы непосредственно характеризовало временные особенности осуществления действия:

> Я *пока* продолжал идти по тропинке.

Здесь можно посмотреть типичные разграничительные примеры из статьи толкового словаря:
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x